# Regular expression for specific special characters

Tags: c#, regex

How can I write a regular expression that would allow alphabets,numbers,space and following special characters `,-/.#\`

For example it should accept these two:

```
916 1/2 W 6#TH ST, Davenport, IA, 52802-3431
100-1/2 Duke Street, 22314
```

I have little knowledge of writing Regular expressions and I'm currently asked to modify a code so plz excuse me for posting this question. Learning regex would take time and I dont have it at hand

Comment: *it should parse these two* => Parse? Did you mean accept? Did you try anything?

Comment: @ThomasAyoub yes edited

Comment: you should google. you will find 100's of answers.

Comment: `Learning regex would take time and I dont have it at hand` Leads me to believe you made no effort.  This is a very simple regex and would take even a beginner about 10 minutes of research to do.

Comment: In the upper right corner of this page find `Search Q&A`. Enter `regex special characters`. Pick the answer most suitable for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You asked `alphabets,numbers,space and following special characters ,-/.#\`

- Alphabets, numbers : `[a-zA-Z0-9]`
- Space : `[ ]`
- Special chars :   `[,\/.#\\-]`
- From end to end : `^$`
- Any length : `*`

Shuffle it together : `^[a-zA-Z0-9 ,\/.#\\-]*$`

Make it C# friendly: `@"^[a-zA-Z0-9 ,\/.#\\-]*$"`...

Comment: Thank you so much Thomas! Your answer not only answers my question but also gives me a go ahead with regex. Appreciate your response